# Learning to Apply Mathematical Concepts ( i.e. function modelling, etc.)

Tags: mathematical-modeling, applications

Firsty, I want to state my situation clearly. I am one of those students who are incredibly good at absorbing mathematical concepts but without knowing how to apply them. I get A's but it is growing on me the idea of an emptiness of comprehension. I guess in some sense, I have not understood those concepts completely.

Secondly, I feel like I need to state the reason of why I want to learn how to know applications of mathematics. I am a computer science major. I want to take master's in computer science and get a specialization in Artificial Intelligence. I think that knowing the applications of mathematics right now will help me incredibly well in that field of career.

(Note: Currently, I am on my second year in college.)

For example, I do not know how to use mathematical concepts to model with functions. I do in some basic sense know how to do it but not completely.

Will someone share some insights on how they did become successful in this endeavor? I know there is some subjectivity in this question but I think that many people have the same question as I do.